# Model creation order when testing in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, testing

I’ve got these two models (examples) and when I’m trying to run my tests - it errors out saying: `no such table: my_app_modelA` - if I scroll up I can see that it is bombing out when creating `modelB` (which I assume is due to the `default` being applied). Is there a way to order these so that `modelA` will always get created before `modelB`? Or should I not be referencing that method as a default attribute? Just trying to get my tests working and this is my sticking point.

My models look like this:

```
class modelA(models.Model):
    attribute = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    @classmethod
    def get_active_attribute(cls):
        return modelA.objects.get(active=True).attribute

class modelB(models.Model):
    attribute = models.IntegerField(default=modelA.get_active_attribute())
```

My questions are:

- Is that an acceptable thing to do - having default call another model method?
- Is there a way to handle the creation of those models in a way that I can guarantee that `modelA` gets created first so `modelB` can succesfully create in my tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the migrations happen in the order which is defined when migration file is created.

```
# 0001_initial.py
...
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name=modelA,
        ....
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name=modelB,
        ....
    ),
]
```

You can check your migration files and make sure `modelA` is before `modelB`.

Secondly, `modelA.get_active_attribute()` needs a DB entry to be able to return something. While running migrations, you are not inserting data. So you should not be declaring `default` by other model's object.
You should instead override `save()` to ensure the default value is based on `modelA`'s attribute.

```
class modelB(models.Model):
    attribute = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.attribute is None:
            self.attribute = modelA.get_active_attribute()
        super(modelB, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I believe this to be the correct answer. The migrations are created in such a way that `modelA` migration is created *after* `modelB`, but in the initial migration it uses a static `Integer`. It wasn't until a much later change that the previous developer changed it to use that method. Which now, after seeing your answer, seems like a bad idea in practice. In production, there would *always* be a DB entry for that to return something - except obviously - in tests, which is where I'm at. Trying to wrangle this back under test. Thanks for your input!